# Good database design - where to store timestamp of events / function executions

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Lets say I have some function `get_inventory_report()` that pulls a report from a server and updates values in my database.

I only want to get the report once every 24 hours so I need to somehow store the date and time that the report was pulled and then have a function like `should_pull_inventory_report()` which simply checks if the time that the report was last pulled is greater the set pull frequency.

I'm thinking the report pull frequency can be stored in a table called `config`, but what I'm not sure of is where or how to store the value for when the report was last pulled.

Essentially, I want to log the time and date of last successful executions of functions (report pulls, API requests) somewhere so that they can later be referenced to determine if enough time has passed that the function needs to be called again.

Comment: Are you re-inventing MySQL's built-in [Events Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)?

Comment: You can use MySQL's scheduled events or an external event scheduler such as cron to schedule the run of a report and update of database. There is no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you.